# How can I get a different percentage unit in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap, I have the following markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
</div>
```

In other places it is also:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6"></div>
  <div class="col-6"></div>
</div>
```

Point being, the `col-x` element can be of arbitrary size (height and width, as, height will be a function of the content inside it.)

I'm rendering `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements on all the `col-x` classes and I need a way to get constant measurement for either the height or width. As in:

```css
/* let's say col-x is a class I add to the elements */
.col-x::before{
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    height: 10%;
    width: calc(height * 2); /* I need this width to be double the heigh. 20% would 20% of the width, not twice the height */
    background-color: white;
    border-top-left-radius: calc(10% + 1rem);  /* 100px of height + 10px of border */
    border-top-right-radius: calc(10% + 1rem); /* 100px of height + 10px of border */
    border: 1rem solid var(--edge4);
    border-bottom: 0;
    top: -5rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: @MisterJojo the Bootstrap grid is a `flexbox`

Comment: @tacoshy all versions ?

Comment: @MisterJojo at least since version 2. But this code must be at least version 3. As `col` was introduced in v3. v2 used `span`-classes instead.

Comment: @MisterJojo This is bootstrap v5.

Comment: If you want to know the exact height and width that particular col-* takes,you can knows using chrome dev tools also.Just right click and inspect element and in computed you will see the details of that particular.